# Ошибка Cannot read property 'Plugins' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, карусель

Всем привет! Хочу подключить плагин карусели, который позволяет выводить слайды в 2 строки, но `Cannot read property 'Plugins' of undefined`, где ругается на строчку `$.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins['owl2row'] = Owl2row;` 
Где-то ошибка?

```js
$(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  Owl2row = function(scope) {
    this.owl = scope;
    this.owl.options = $.extend(Owl2row.Defaults, this.owl.options);
    //link callback events with owl carousel here

    this.handlers = {
      'initialize.owl.carousel': $.proxy(function(e) {
        if (this.owl.settings.owl2row) {
          this.build2row(this);
        }
      }, this)
    };

    this.owl.$element.on(this.handlers);
  };

  Owl2row.Defaults = {
    owl2row: 'true',
    owl2rowTarget: 'item',
    owl2rowContainer: 'owl2row-item',
    owl2rowDirection: 'utd' // ltr
  };

  //mehtods:
  Owl2row.prototype.build2row = function(thisScope) {

    var carousel = $('.' + thisScope.owl.options.baseClass);
    var carouselItems = carousel.find('.' + thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowTarget);

    var aEvenElements = [];
    var aOddElements = [];

    $.each(carouselItems, function(index, item) {
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        aEvenElements.push(item);
      } else {
        aOddElements.push(item);
      }
    });

    carousel.empty();

    switch (thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowDirection) {
      case 'ltr':
        thisScope.leftToright(thisScope, carousel, carouselItems);
        break;

      default:
        thisScope.upTodown(thisScope, aEvenElements, aOddElements, carousel);
    }

  };

  Owl2row.prototype.leftToright = function(thisScope, carousel, carouselItems) {

    var o2wContainerClass = thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowContainer;
    var owlMargin = thisScope.owl.options.margin;

    var carouselItemsLength = carouselItems.length;

    var firsArr = [];
    var secondArr = [];

    //console.log(carouselItemsLength);

    if (carouselItemsLength % 2 === 1) {
      carouselItemsLength = ((carouselItemsLength - 1) / 2) + 1;
    } else {
      carouselItemsLength = carouselItemsLength / 2;
    }

    //console.log(carouselItemsLength);

    $.each(carouselItems, function(index, item) {


      if (index < carouselItemsLength) {
        firsArr.push(item);
      } else {
        secondArr.push(item);
      }
    });

    $.each(firsArr, function(index, item) {
      var rowContainer = $('<div class="' + o2wContainerClass + '"/>');

      var firstRowElement = firsArr[index];
      firstRowElement.style.marginBottom = owlMargin + 'px';

      rowContainer
        .append(firstRowElement)
        .append(secondArr[index]);

      carousel.append(rowContainer);
    });

  };

  Owl2row.prototype.upTodown = function(thisScope, aEvenElements, aOddElements, carousel) {

    var o2wContainerClass = thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowContainer;
    var owlMargin = thisScope.owl.options.margin;

    $.each(aEvenElements, function(index, item) {

      var rowContainer = $('<div class="' + o2wContainerClass + '"/>');
      var evenElement = aEvenElements[index];

      evenElement.style.marginBottom = owlMargin + 'px';

      rowContainer
        .append(evenElement)
        .append(aOddElements[index]);

      carousel.append(rowContainer);
    });
  };

  /**
   * Destroys the plugin.
   */
  Owl2row.prototype.destroy = function() {
    var handler, property;

    for (handler in this.handlers) {
      this.owl.dom.$el.off(handler, this.handlers[handler]);
    }
    for (property in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
      typeof this[property] !== 'function' && (this[property] = null);
    }
  };



  $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins['owl2row'] = Owl2row;
})(window.Zepto || window.jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка потому что: `Constructor == undefined` попробуйте так:

```
var constructor = $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor || {};
constructor.Plugins = constructor.Plugins || {};
constructor.Plugins['owl2row'] = Owl2row;
$.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor = constructor;
```

А почему вы сразу не присвоили `$.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor = Owl2row`? Мне кажется такой вариант логичнее.

```js
(function($, window, document, undefined) { // Тут $ в начале функции не нужен, конструкция $(function ...) используется для выполнения функции в скобках после загрузки страницы.
  var Owl2row = function(scope) { // Не забываете ставить var перед переменными, а иначе переменная Owl2row будет глобальной
    this.owl = scope;
    this.owl.options = $.extend(Owl2row.Defaults, this.owl.options);
    //link callback events with owl carousel here

    this.handlers = {
      'initialize.owl.carousel': $.proxy(function(e) {
        if (this.owl.settings.owl2row) {
          this.build2row(this);
        }
      }, this)
    };

    this.owl.$element.on(this.handlers);
  };

  Owl2row.Defaults = {
    owl2row: 'true',
    owl2rowTarget: 'item',
    owl2rowContainer: 'owl2row-item',
    owl2rowDirection: 'utd' // ltr
  };

  //mehtods:
  Owl2row.prototype.build2row = function(thisScope) {

    var carousel = $('.' + thisScope.owl.options.baseClass);
    var carouselItems = carousel.find('.' + thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowTarget);

    var aEvenElements = [];
    var aOddElements = [];

    $.each(carouselItems, function(index, item) {
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        aEvenElements.push(item);
      } else {
        aOddElements.push(item);
      }
    });

    carousel.empty();

    switch (thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowDirection) {
      case 'ltr':
        thisScope.leftToright(thisScope, carousel, carouselItems);
        break;

      default:
        thisScope.upTodown(thisScope, aEvenElements, aOddElements, carousel);
    }

  };

  Owl2row.prototype.leftToright = function(thisScope, carousel, carouselItems) {

    var o2wContainerClass = thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowContainer;
    var owlMargin = thisScope.owl.options.margin;

    var carouselItemsLength = carouselItems.length;

    var firsArr = [];
    var secondArr = [];

    //console.log(carouselItemsLength);

    if (carouselItemsLength % 2 === 1) {
      carouselItemsLength = ((carouselItemsLength - 1) / 2) + 1;
    } else {
      carouselItemsLength = carouselItemsLength / 2;
    }

    //console.log(carouselItemsLength);

    $.each(carouselItems, function(index, item) {


      if (index < carouselItemsLength) {
        firsArr.push(item);
      } else {
        secondArr.push(item);
      }
    });

    $.each(firsArr, function(index, item) {
      var rowContainer = $('<div class="' + o2wContainerClass + '"/>');

      var firstRowElement = firsArr[index];
      firstRowElement.style.marginBottom = owlMargin + 'px';

      rowContainer
        .append(firstRowElement)
        .append(secondArr[index]);

      carousel.append(rowContainer);
    });

  };

  Owl2row.prototype.upTodown = function(thisScope, aEvenElements, aOddElements, carousel) {

    var o2wContainerClass = thisScope.owl.options.owl2rowContainer;
    var owlMargin = thisScope.owl.options.margin;

    $.each(aEvenElements, function(index, item) {

      var rowContainer = $('<div class="' + o2wContainerClass + '"/>');
      var evenElement = aEvenElements[index];

      evenElement.style.marginBottom = owlMargin + 'px';

      rowContainer
        .append(evenElement)
        .append(aOddElements[index]);

      carousel.append(rowContainer);
    });
  };

  /**
   * Destroys the plugin.
   */
  Owl2row.prototype.destroy = function() {
    var handler, property;

    for (handler in this.handlers) {
      this.owl.dom.$el.off(handler, this.handlers[handler]);
    }
    for (property in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
      typeof this[property] !== 'function' && (this[property] = null);
    }
  };

  // В случае если $.fn.owlCarousel где-то определен, проигнорируйте эту часть кода.
  $.fn.owlCarousel = function(scope) {
    // Сам плагин, я не нашел определения в вашем примере
    new Owl2row(scope); // Создаем сам плагин. Это очень простой пример и я вам рекомендую посмотреть как реализованы плагины например у bootstrap: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/alert.js#L61
    return this; // this - это jQuery объект к которому применяется плагин, считается хорошим тоном возвращать this в функции плагина
  }


  // Следующий код обычно не влияет на работу плагина и используется для того чтобы открыть доступ к конструктору, обычно это нужно для тестов
  $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor = {} // Constructor равен undefined, а нам нужно присвоить пустой объект. Если $.fn.owlCarousel - не ваш плагин, то будет лучше использовать кострукцию $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor = $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor || {};
  $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins = {} // Тоже самое что и с Constructor
  $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins.owl2row = Owl2row; // записи Plugins.owl2row и Plugins['owl2row'] эквивалентны
})(window.Zepto || window.jQuery, window, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: как не присвоил? а это `$.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins['owl2row'] = Owl2row;` не тоже самое? а куда вы предлагаете связку выше поместить?

Comment: Вставил сниппет с переделанным кодом, надеюсь стало понятнее. У вас используется строка `$.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins['owl2row'] = Owl2row;` а я предложил `$.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor = Owl2row;`. Но в случае если `$.fn.owlCarousel` определен где-то не в вашем плагине и требует именно такого синтаксиса `$.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins['owl2row']` то вам нужно присвоить `Constructor` и `Plugins` пустой объект, если они равны `undefined`, для этого и нужна конструкция такого вида: `$.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor = $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor || {}`.